How to Download Artifacts from a Different GitHub Actions Pipeline?
I'm working with GitHub Actions and have encountered an issue with downloading artifacts across different pipelines. While artifacts can be successfully downloaded between jobs within the same pipeline, I need to download artifacts in a different pipeline. Below are the CI and CD pipelines I'm using and the error I'm encountering.
CI Pipeline:
name: CI Workflow

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]

jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}

      - name: List commits in PR
        id: list-commits
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TOKEN_GITHUB }}
        run: |
          pr_number=${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}
          commits=$(gh pr view $pr_number --json commits --jq '.commits[].oid')
          echo "Commit hashes from stage branch:"
          echo "$commits"
          echo "$commits" > commit-hashes.txt
      - name: Save commits to artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: commit-hashes
          path: commit-hashes.txt

CD Pipeline:
name: CD Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  cd:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Download artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: commit-hashes
          path: .

      - name: Display commits
        run: |
          echo "Commits in this PR:"
          cat commit-hashes.txt

Error:
Downloading single artifact
Error: Unable to download artifact(s): Artifact not found for name: commit-hashes
        Please ensure that your artifact is not expired and the artifact was uploaded using a compatible version of toolkit/upload-artifact.
        For more information, visit the GitHub Artifacts FAQ: https://github.com/actions/toolkit/blob/main/packages/artifact/docs/faq.md

Expected Requirement:
The artifacts uploaded in the CI pipeline should be accessible and downloadable in the CD pipeline.
Questions:
How can I enable downloading artifacts across different GitHub Actions pipelines?
Are there any additional configurations required to make artifacts from one pipeline accessible to another?
Any guidance or examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!
Notes: Pipeline CI and CD belongs to same projects
